# What is a good way to create SAR archives with maven?

Tags: java, build, maven, maven-plugin, sar

Actually i found the Maven plugin maven-sar-plugin. It was last published on 2007-11-06.

Is there a more uptodate way to create an sar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [JBoss Packaging Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is just what I need. Do you know whether it is possible to build multiple artifacts from one module? E.g. a sar with some mbeans and a jar containing other code.

Comment: The idea in maven is to have one artifact per module, so I suggest adding an extra module for the jar and including it in the sar if needed